# Trying to export a model from keras to CoreML

Tags: python, keras, coreml, coremltools

This is my first project using keras.

The idea is to create a model that can identify the color of wood. If a color is the one I am identifying I get a `1` if it is not I get a `0`.

I have a `csv` file like this:

```
red,green,blue,isWood
63,110,255,0
58,104,255,0
63,112,255,0
96,141,198,1
95,140,197,1
95,138,195,1
```

I have created this model based on the combination of several tutorials I have found on the web.

```
import pandas as pd

train_df = pd.read_csv('woodData.csv')

train_df.head()

#create a dataframe with all training data except the target column
train_X = train_df.drop(columns=['isWood'])

#check that the target variable has been removed
train_X.head()

#create a dataframe with only the target column
train_y = train_df[['isWood']]

#view dataframe
train_y.head()

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
#create model
model = Sequential()

#get number of columns in training data
n_cols = train_X.shape[1]

#add model layers
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

#compile model using mse as a measure of model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# LINE 1
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, ['red','green','blue'], 'isWood')
coreml_model.input_description['red'] = 'red value'
coreml_model.input_description['green'] = 'green value'
coreml_model.input_description['blue'] = 'blue value'
coreml_model.output_description['isWood'] = '1 = is wood, 0 is not wood'
coreml_model.save('wood.mlmodel')
```

This app crashed on line

```
coreml_model.input_description['green'] = 'green value'
```

with the following error message:

```
Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
     77                 f.shortDescription = value
     78                 return
---> 79         raise AttributeError("No feature with name %s." % key)
     80 
     81     def __iter__(self):

AttributeError: No feature with name green.
```

I have tried to modify `LINE 1` to

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, input_names=['red','green','blue'], output_names='isWood')
```

or

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, input_names=['red','green','blue'], output_names=['isWood'])
```

with no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your Keras model only has one input (with 3 features) so you can only give one input name in `coremltools.converters.keras.convert`.

Try replacing `LINE 1` with the following:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, 'rgb-color', 'isWood')
```

Comment: so, how do I write `LINE 1`?

Comment: for example `coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, 'rgb-image', 'isWood')`